# Use gson to parse json array with both string and another array in it?

Tags: java, android, arrays, json, gson

Please see the following json

```
{ "somekey" : 
    { "data" : [[
        "1", 
        "this is 2 ind index data", 
        ["one", "two", "three", "four", "five"]
    ]]}
}
```

The above is the structure of my json data is an array with 2 string and one array in it how can I achieve to parse the response using Gson

The following are the model class I written
**BaseData.java**

```
class BaseData
{
public SomeData somekey;
}
```

**SomeData.java**

```
class SomeData
{
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> data
}
```

and after getting the response usual gson function I called

```
 new  Gson().fromJson("above response string here", BaseData.class);
```

But I get the following error

> 07-31 17:26:14.824 28099-28099/ W/System.err: Caused by:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected a string but was BEGIN_ARRAY
>   at line 1 column 253 path $.

I understand that it is because of the array model I have made I have made only array to accept string but how can I fix it, So that I can accept string and array together in and array response like this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use `Arraylist<Arraylist<Object>>` since you have different types  in that list

Your extraction code must be cast those later to get the correct type

Answer (score 0):

You need the structure like this:

```
class BaseData {
     SomeKey somekey;
}
class SomeKey {
     List<ArrayEntity> data;
}
class ArrayEntity {
     int firstVar;
     String secondVar;
     List<String> thirdVar;
}
```

and use it like this:

```
 new  Gson().fromJson("above response string here", BaseData.class);
```

Comment: `ArrayEntity` isn't an object in the JSON

Comment: as @cricket_007 ArrayEntity isn't an object in the JSON

Comment: @Ramz my fault. if ArrayEntity the same, in the SomeKey we need to use List<List<ArrayEntity>>. If not - List<List<Map<String,String>> and parse it manually

Comment: List<List<Map<String,String>> is wrong for the same reason. There aren't objects within the inner list, only string and list